# What kind of butterfly is a 「ゼッコーちょう」?

Tags: meaning, puns

In the video game "Tingle's Love Balloon Trip", a person asks the protagonist to catch a certain kind of butterfly. They want the dust from the butterfly's wings to use as a kind of fertilizer. The name of this butterfly is 「ゼッコーチョウ」. Here is the relevant bit of dialogue:

> ゼッコーチョウ っていう チョウを つかまえて ほしいの。ハネが もえあがるような はでな ルックス なんだって !

Now I know that ちょう means butterfly, but I can't make head or tail of ゼッコー, so I'm assuming it must be a pun of some sort.

What could be the meaning of this name?

Comment: Did you find [絶好調](http://beta.jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93%E3%81%86%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%86) (ぜっこうちょう)?

Comment: No I didn't, because I only searched for ぜっこー, not ぜっこう. That must be the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a pun.

「[絶好調]{ぜっこうちょう}」 is a word meaning "top form", "best condition", etc.

And as you said, 「[蝶]{ちょう}」 means a "butterfly".

Types of butterflies are named 「～～蝶」, so there you go.